# Bazel equivalent of Buck's classpath

Tags: java, bazel

I'm trying to migrate a project from buck to bazel and looking for an equivalent of the *$(classpath)* macro available for genrules. Is there anything similar available in bazel to get a list of jars for the classpath of a given java_library?

The best I could come up with is iterating over the list of dependencies and using the *$(execpath)* macro to get the correspondent jar:

```py
jar_deps = []
for dep in deps: # deps are the same dependencies specified for the java_library
    jar_deps.append("$(execpath %s)" % dep)

genrule(
    name = "test-rule",
    outs = ["test-rule.txt"],
    deps = deps,
    cmd  = "echo \"%s\" > $@" % (":".join(jar_deps)),
)
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like another way to achieve this is by using a custom rule accessing the Java rule's *JavaInfo* provider:

```py
def _runtime_deps_providing_rule_impl(ctx):
  return [
    platform_common.TemplateVariableInfo({
      "RUNTIME_DEPS": ":".join([f.path for f in ctx.attr.rule[JavaInfo].transitive_runtime_deps.to_list()]),
    })
  ]

runtime_deps_providing_rule = rule(
  implementation = _runtime_deps_providing_rule_impl,
  attrs = {
    "rule": attr.label(),
  },
)

runtime_deps_providing_rule(
  name = "test-providing-rule",
  rule = ":test-java-rule",
)

genrule(
  name = "test-rule",
  outs = ["test-rule.txt"],
  cmd = "echo \"$(RUNTIME_DEPS)\" > $@",
  toolchains = [":test-providing-rule"],
)
```

The advantage of this is that there is no need to explicitly pass the list of dependencies around.